# Node.js+ Socket.io : how to manage different chats

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm looking for solution for these requirements:

1. web-chat for many clients with operator via browser from different sites (domains);
   operator serve only his site, for ex.:

   site1->chat1->operator1

   site2->chat2->operator2
2. server side shoud be know which client go to from site and route his into chat1 or chat2 (it depends of domain name);
3. server side support of unlimited clients
4. server side support of unlimited domains

I look in the direction node.js+socket.io, and understand how to route client and operator for one chat-domain,

like this on server side:

```
app.get('/admin', function(req, res, next) {
       res.sendfile(__dirname + '/admin.html');
       next();

});

app.get('/user', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
        next();
});
```

if we need route messages from different sites i can use this variant for ex. where  for id-param set value of domain-id

```
app.get('/admin/:id?', function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/admin'+id+'.html');
        next();

});

app.get('/user/:id?', function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index'+id+'.html');
        next();
});
```

have questions:

1. main  - chain node.js+socket.io is correct solution for it ?
2. how set the same logic of io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {}
   for all domains (user & admin)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a good solution

And you are using namespaces for different types of users, and you can use rooms to manage each type of users 
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/rooms

and this is the full documentation 
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki